# Xcode 10 C++ bug (can't input in console without output first)

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode10

Recently I updated to Xcode 10 Now I make C++ project usually with macos command line tool and found this bug. Now when I build and run without output first the console doesnt appear and hangs. If I ouput first then console comes and then you can input according to your program.

Without printing output first console hangs and no input can be done:

[image]
Console appears after output first in program:

EDITED : Getting this problem again with Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

[image]

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.  Worked on my machine.  Compiled with `/usr/bin/clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -std=c++17 code.cpp`, ran with `./a.out`, entered `38`.

Comment: @Eljay how do i changed compiler to clang++ i am new to xcode

Comment: clang++ is the compiler that comes with Xcode 10.

Comment: How do you build and run do u build and run in terminal? in xcode i build with c++ source compiler

Comment: I open Terminal.app and run the command as per my comment, then run the executable that gets built.  If you are more comfortable in Xcode, you can do it from there too.

Comment: i am having problem with compiling with xcode it hangs at the output console if output is not first can you check using xcode?

Comment: I checked using Xcode 10, and ran into the same problem.  You'll either have to do a workaround, or file a RADAR bug with Apple and do the workaround until they fix the problem.

Comment: If you do this... `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` ...as the very first line in your `main`, it seems to fix the issue (whatever the underlying issue is).

Comment: @Eljay yeah it fix the issue but we cant type it everytime apple should fix the issue asap i reported bug btw

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm this. The same problem, can't see input in the first line. The only workaround I found is making some output in the beginning of the program.